# Java , advantages of usage of multiple scanner object instead of one

Tags: java

What is the advantage of using multiple Scanner object to input different data type from standard input, when it can be accomplished by using only single Scanner object.

For example:

---

```
public class Etc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String name;
            int y;
            Scanner inputString= new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner inputint=new Scanner(System.in);
            name=inputString.nextLine();
            y=inputint.nextInt();
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Etc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String name;
            int y;
            Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
            name=input.nextLine();
            y=input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels quite opinion-based and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like :

```
y=input.nextInt();
name=input.nextLine();
```

Then the [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method does not consume the *last newline* character of your input, and thus that *newline* is consumed in the next call to [`Scanner#nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)
This will make your name blank.

In your example you have nextLine followed by nextInt that is why you don't see the problem. If you inverse it you will see the problem.

I'm not sure if this is only reason to do it this way but this may be one of the reasons to use 2 different streams.

**NOTE**: You will encounter the similar behaviour when you use `Scanner#nextLine` after [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) or any `Scanner#nextFoo` method (except `nextLine` itself).

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage I would see to use differents Scanner objects is when using multiple input streams.

For example :

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(myFile);
```

When using one stream only, stick to one and only `Scanner` object.

And I personnaly think the best to do is to define it as a private static final variable of your class and instanciate it from the beginning.

Here's an example :

```
public class MyClass{
    private static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args){ //blabla }

    // Random stuff
}
```